# Xamarin Forms: IMarkupExtension with bindable property does not work

Tags: image, xamarin, xamarin.forms, data-binding, bindable

The binding is not working for the Image tag.
When I debug, I see that the value of the Source in Extension class is always null?
But the content of the label is not null.

### Xaml

```xml
<Label Text="{Binding Image}" />
<Image Source="{classes:ImageResource Source={Binding Image}}" />
```

### ImageResourceExtension

```cs
// You exclude the 'Extension' suffix when using in Xaml markup
[Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
[ContentProperty("Source")]
public class ImageResourceExtension : BindableObject, IMarkupExtension
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty SourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Source), typeof(string), typeof(string), null);
    public string Source
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(SourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (Source == null)
            return null;

        // Do your translation lookup here, using whatever method you require
        var imageSource = ImageSource.FromResource(Source);

        return imageSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to load an image which is an embedded resource or is it an asset?

Comment: Haven't tried your example, but the BindableProperty is declared incorrectly. The declaring type parameter should be typeof(ImageResourceExtension) rather than typeof(string). But also as mentioned in the answer below, you should use a converter instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Of course it does not !

It's not because you inherit from `BindableObject` that magically your object has a `BindingContext` set. And without a `BindingContext`, there's no way to resolve the `{Binding Image}`.

What you're looking for here is a Converter

```
class ImageSourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object ConvertTo (object value, ...)
    {
        return ImageSource.FromResource(Source);
    }

    public object ConvertFrom (object value, ...)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException ();
    }
}
```

You then add this converter to your Xaml root element resources (or Application.Resources and use it in your Bindings

```xml
<Label Text="{Binding Image}" />
<Image Source="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}" />
```

Comment: Suppose you need to pass more than one parameter, one of which is a bound value?  I have a converter that I started to rework into custom markup, to add a third input [which is not bound], until I discovered the custom markup couldn't handle the binding.

Comment: nm, I just found this: [Converter with multipler parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323169/converter-with-multiple-parameter).